# Trying to create a dynamic merge script and passing the variables dynamically

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to create a dynamic merge script and pass the variables dynamically, but the variable are not getting substituted in the code. Can someone help on this?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE MERGE_APPMODULE(institutionKey varchar2,applname varchar2,modulename varchar2,DESCRIPTION varchar2 )
as
--set serveroutput on;
--SET FEEDBACK OFF;

DATA long;
BEGIN
select

CONCAT ('declare
  institutionkey varchar2(100) := '|| '''institutionkey''' ||' ;
  actiondate DATE  := SYSDATE;
  actionuser VARCHAR2(100) := sys_context(''USERENV'', ''AUTHENTICATED_IDENTITY'');
  supportedLanguages varchar2(100) := ''en'';
BEGIN',
  '
    MERGE INTO APPMODULE TARGET 
        USING (
                SELECT  0 DISALLOW, NULL IMAGE, NULL IsMaintainence, moduleclass,1 ModuleIndex, ''modulename'' ModuleName , ApplId FROM APPLICATION WHERE  ApplName = ''applname''  and FinInstKey = ''institutionKey'')
               ) source 
        ON (
            target.ApplId=source.ApplId and target.ModuleName=source.ModuleName
            )
       WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
          insert (createddate, creatorusr, Disallow, Image, IsDefault, IsMaintainence, moduleClass, ModuleIndex, ModuleName, updatordate, updatorusr, ApplId) 
          values (actionDate, actionUser, source.Disallow, source.Image, 1, source.IsMaintainence, source.moduleClass, source.ModuleIndex, source.ModuleName, actionDate, actionUser, source.ApplId); 

    MERGE INTO APPMODULETXT target
        USING (
                SELECT ''DESCRIPTION'' DESCRIPTION, ModuleId FROM AppModule m JOIN Application a ON m.ApplId = a.ApplId WHERE m.ModuleName = ''ACCOUNTS_SERVICES_MODULE'' AND a.ApplName = applicationName AND a.finInstKey = ''institutionKey'' 

        ) source 
        ON (
               target.ModuleId = source.ModuleId
            )
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            insert (Description, TxtLanguage, ModuleId) 
            values (source.Description, ''en'', source.ModuleId);') INTO DATA from dual;

        dbms_output.put_line(DATA);  
  END;
```

Comment: I have tried that that and it works for me, i want to try something dynamic

Comment: The thing which i am trying is useful for my to implement , so i am trying this.

Comment: If you say so. However your posted code demonstrates absolutely no benefit from dynamic SQL whatsoever, while making it harder to understand and more brittle to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing concatanation properly.

Strings can be concated using `||` operaror or `concat` method.

In your code you used both and mess happened. Here, I tried using `||` operator as following:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE MERGE_APPMODULE(institutionKey varchar2,applname varchar2,modulename varchar2,DESCRIPTION varchar2 )
as
--set serveroutput on;
--SET FEEDBACK OFF;

DATA VARCHAR2(32767); -- using varchar2 data type variable
BEGIN
DATA := 'declare
  institutionkey varchar2(100) := '''|| institutionkey ||''' ;
  actiondate DATE  := SYSDATE;
  actionuser VARCHAR2(100) := sys_context(''USERENV'', ''AUTHENTICATED_IDENTITY'');
  supportedLanguages varchar2(100) := ''en'';
BEGIN' || chr(10) ||
  ' MERGE INTO APPMODULE TARGET 
        USING (
                SELECT  0 DISALLOW, NULL IMAGE, NULL IsMaintainence, moduleclass,1 ModuleIndex, '''|| modulename ||''' ModuleName , ApplId FROM APPLICATION WHERE  ApplName = ''' || applname || ''' and FinInstKey = ''' || institutionKey || '''
               ) source 
        ON (
            target.ApplId=source.ApplId and target.ModuleName=source.ModuleName
            )
       WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
          insert (createddate, creatorusr, Disallow, Image, IsDefault, IsMaintainence, moduleClass, ModuleIndex, ModuleName, updatordate, updatorusr, ApplId) 
          values (actionDate, actionUser, source.Disallow, source.Image, 1, source.IsMaintainence, source.moduleClass, source.ModuleIndex, source.ModuleName, actionDate, actionUser, source.ApplId); 

    MERGE INTO APPMODULETXT target
        USING (
                SELECT ''' || DESCRIPTION || ''' DESCRIPTION, ModuleId FROM AppModule m JOIN Application a ON m.ApplId = a.ApplId WHERE m.ModuleName = ''ACCOUNTS_SERVICES_MODULE'' AND a.ApplName = applicationName AND a.finInstKey = ''' || institutionKey || '''  
               ) source 
        ON (
               target.ModuleId = source.ModuleId
            )
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            insert (Description, TxtLanguage, ModuleId) 
            values (source.Description, ''en'', source.ModuleId);';

        dbms_output.put_line(DATA);  
  END;
```

Check if it is working for you.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks Tejash!, your code is working and i have fixed mine as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using type LONG in this century?
It has been sort of deprecated since Oracle 8.0 came out in 1997.

Using CLOB will generally make your life a lot easier, but in this case even a VARCHAR2 is probably large enough to fit your query.